# Как работать с данными из внешних источников?

Tags: sql, delphi, база-данных

В какую структуру нужно считать данные из внешних файлов, чтобы к ним можно было делать SQL запросы? Считал в dxMemData(DataSet), но Select из нескольких DataSet похоже не возможен? Создавать из них отдельную БД не удобно, т.к. данные часто обновляются. Как лучше поступить в таком случае?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что вопрос изначально возник от неправильного подхода к планированию. Вопрос из серии "а давайте придумаем что нибудь такое, чтобы из Петербурга попасть в Москву через Сахалин?" Это не должно прозвучать обидно, но зачем же создавать **в пямяти Delphi-приложения** базу данных? Зачем "наковыривать" из текстовых файлов какие-то строки, чтобы загнать их в какую-то структуру в памяти, к которой потом неизвестно как обращаться?

Зачем городить огород, когда есть куча решений по интеграции и унификации потоков данных. Есть в конце-концов Базы Данных любого уровня. От начального до профессионального.

Самое логичное решение:

- установить простую БД (например Access, SQL Server Express или др.)
- Парсить "кучу текстовых файлов в виде скриптов с массивами" и складывать результаты парсинга в БД.
- Обращаться к БД стандартными SQL-запросами;
- Profit!

P.S. На момент написания ответа, мне недоступны стредства комментирования. Поэтому я оформляю мой пост в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен правильный подход к считыванию данных из БД.
У вас есть база данных, делайте к ней запросы с получением уже готового требуемого окончательного набора данных. Максимум что можно делать в ПО, так это фильтровать этот готовый набор, ну и всякие биндинги к другим компонентам.
В Delphi DataSet максимум могут быть зависимыми, но это сложный фильтр между ними устанавливается. Но запросы делаются к базе данных, а не к компонентам среды разработки.

Comment: Так нет БД, в этом то и проблема... Есть куча текстовых файлов в виде скриптов с массивами из которых парсятся данные и создаются таблички.

Comment: Текстовые файлы разбираются построчно, какие могут быть к ним запросы. (конечно есть варианты если это файлы на подобии Excel.. имеющие структуру), ну а если просто блокнот со строчками - вот и обрабатывайте строчки. А мой вам совет - создайте локальную базу данных  и тогда ей пользуйтесь, если у вас нет сетевой. И импортируйте данные из файлов в нее и потом уже запросы. Проще будет.

Comment: А виртуальную БД возможно создать? Которая бы существовала только на момент работы программы

Comment: Да в Delphi есть такая возможность. Создается таблица, с колонками у нее указывается режим виртуальной (если правильно помню), но к сожалению пример не приведу... это я делал много лет назад. Уж не помню.

Comment: Но если таких табличек будет несколько, то Select из них тоже будет не возможен, т.к. это просто разные компоненты, так ведь?

Comment: @Isaev, по-моему да (не помню как это создается). Я вам посоветую использовать SQLite. Подключается в виде библиотеки DLL работает удобно и понятно.
http://www.delphi.int.ru/articles/43/